# Is $f : \Bbb R\:\to[0, +\infty)$, defined by $f(x)=x^2$, continuous around $0$ with respect to the topological definition of continuity?

Tags: general-topology

Is $f : \Bbb R \to [0 ,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$ continuous around $0$ with respect to the topological definition of continuity?

I had recently started studying topology when I came across the above discrepancy between the definitions of continuity using topology and limits.
As no open set in the range of the above function can include $0$, the topological definition does not refer to continuity around $0$.

Comment: Please see this for a LaTeX tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also the answer to your question has to do with what the open sets in $[0,\infty)$ look like. The topology on $[0,\infty)$ is the subspace topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, so open sets are obtained by intersecting open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with $[0,\infty)$. In particular the claim that "no open set in the range can include $0$" is false.

Comment: @A.G You have posted **eight** questions here, please try to follow the link as suggested by halrankard2

Comment: I am confused by the query.  Every definition of continuity at a specific point $c$ that I have seen considers the region $0 < |c-x| < \delta$ rather than $0 \leq |c-x| < \delta.$  Can you cite a reference that disagrees with my understanding?

Comment: As @halrankard2 has stated, you have to use the subspace topology. There, $[0,\epsilon)$ is an *open* set.

Comment: @user2661923 in topology, a function is continuous iff the inverse image of every open set is open. No need for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose okay.  Bizarre, but thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 well, with the concept of open sets you can have continuous functions even when the Range and Domain do not know of subtraction or absolute values.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Interesting.  In Palka's "An Intro to Complex Function Theory", I actually survived his chapter 2, "The Rudiments of Plane Topology".  Based on that, having continuity without $\epsilon, \delta$ is foreign to me.

Comment: @user2661923 What GyroGearloose says is precisely the topological definition of continuity. It is not at all bizarre, but rather the correct way to deal with general topological spaces that may not have any sense of ordering, etc.  This is what a basic "point-set topology" course would be all about. So what you say about continuity is correct, but the OP is asking how to reconcile that with the *topological definition*.

Comment: @user2661923 for complex functions, there is no need for the abstract concept. It kicks in again when you have to deal with infinite vector spaces.

Comment: By the way, I upvoted to reverse whoever downvoted.  The OP was simply asking for a definition/interpretation, rather than asking for the solution to a problem.  I have a problem seeing such a question downvoted.  I never saw the original query (before halrankard2 edited it), so I can (somewhat) see being unhappy if he refuses to use mathJax.  But downvoting because of no mathJax seems a bit much.  Personally, in such a situation, I would advocate a comment like "please edit with mathJax so that we can respond."

Answer (score 2):

There are two options.

1. Don't treat $f$ as a function to $[0,\infty)$, but as a function to $\mathbb{R}$. Then you can use the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ to show that $f$ is continuous $0$.
2. If you want to treat $f$ as a function to $[0,\infty)$, then you have to make sure you have the correct understanding of what the topology on $[0,\infty)$ looks like. From the way you asked the question, it looks like you are calling a subset of $[0,\infty)$ open only if it is open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. But this does not define a topology on $[0,\infty)$. For example, in any topological space, the whole space must *always* be open set.

The correct topology on $[0,\infty)$ in this case is the *subspace topology*, which has open sets of the form $X\cap [0,\infty)$ where $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So, for example $[0,\infty)$ *is* an open set in the subspace topology since it is of the form $\mathbb{R}\cap [0,\infty)$, and $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, with the correct understanding of the topology on $[0,\infty)$, you can prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$. For example, the preimage of an open set of the form $[0,\epsilon)$ is $(-\sqrt{\epsilon},\sqrt{\epsilon})$, which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.